# Why does my border-box color do not change

Tags: javascript, html, css, authentication

I need to create login form for random user, and when is incorrect password, password box need to be red (border-color), and when it is correct it need to be green. Can you help me with code in Javascript.  And sorry for bad English if I make some mistakes :). Thank you.

I try this, and no color changes.

```js
var users = [{
  username: 'new_user',
  password: "123456789",
}]


function login(email, password) {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value

  for (var user of users) {

    if ((email === user.email || email === user.username) && password === user.password) {
      var block = document.querySelector('.nav');
      block.style.display = "block"
      var errMsg = document.querySelector('.loginForm .errorMessage')
      errMsg.style.display = "none"
      var form = document.querySelector('.loginForm')
      form.style.display = "none"
      var name = document.getElementById("user-name")
      name.innerHTML = user.name;
      loggedUser = user;
      clearValue("email");
      clearValue("password")
    } else {
      var errMsg = document.querySelector('.loginForm .errorMessage')
      errMsg.style.display = "block"
      var passwordBox = document.querySelector(".loginForm input.password")
      passwordBox.style.border.color = "red"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loginForm" class="loginForm">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <input id="email" type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email or Username">
  <input onkeyup="loginOnEnter(event)" id="password" type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password">
  <p class="errorMessage">*please, enter valid password</p>
  <button onclick="login()" class="login-btn">LOG IN</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't set `form.style.[...]` properties, write some CSS classes, and then add/toggle/remove those using the [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API. That way they never "take over" CSS rules from other classes, they get applied following the normal "most specific selector wins" rule of CSS. And they cascade, so you don't need to querySelect four things on the JS side, you just need to set one class and then write normal cascading styles.

Comment: `name.innerHTML = user.name;` <-- Don't use `innerHTML`: that's how you get XSS vulns. Use `innerText` or `textContent` instead.

Comment: Also that. And finally, don't use `on...` HTML attributes to trigger JS, [even MDN warns about that by now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers): add those event listeners on the JS side by querySelecting the elements that need event handling, and then writing a bit of `addEventListener` code for each of them. And if you need to wait for the DOM to be ready: just load your script with `<script src="..." async defer"></script>`, relying on the [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Might be your CSS. Try:

`style.borderColor = 'red';`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var users = [{
  username: 'new_user',
  password: "123456789",
}]


function login(email, password) {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value

  for (var user of users) {

    if ((email === user.email || email === user.username) && password === user.password) {
      document.getElementById("email").style.border = "thick solid #008000";
      document.getElementById("password").style.border = "thick solid #008000";
      loggedUser = user;
       document.getElementById("email").value = "";
  document.getElementById("password").value = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("email").style.border = "thick solid #FF0000";
      document.getElementById("password").style.border = "thick solid #FF0000";
     
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loginForm" class="loginForm">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <input id="email" type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email or Username">
  <input  id="password" type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password">
  <p class="errorMessage">*please, enter valid password</p>
  <button onclick="login()" class="login-btn">LOG IN</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `borderColor` instead of `border.color`

```js
      function login(email, password) {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        for (var user of users) {
          if (
            (email === user.email || email === user.username) &&
            password === user.password
          ) {
            var block = document.querySelector(".nav");
            block.style.display = "block";
            var errMsg = document.querySelector(".loginForm .errorMessage");
            errMsg.style.display = "none";
            var form = document.querySelector(".loginForm");
            form.style.display = "none";
            var name = document.getElementById("user-name");
            name.innerHTML = user.name;
            loggedUser = user;
            clearValue("email");
            clearValue("password");
          } else {
            var errMsg = document.querySelector(".loginForm .errorMessage");
            errMsg.style.display = "block";
            var passwordBox = document.querySelector(
              ".loginForm input.password"
            );
            //HERE USE borderColor
            passwordBox.style.borderColor = "red";
          }
        }
      }
```